# Track Clicks on custom JS code deployed through Google Tag Manager GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've deployed a customer service JS code (Tidio) `<script>http://code.tidio.io/ab/abcd.js</script>` via GTM custom HTML tag.

I want to pass information to GA and track event clicks on the chat custom code i.e. when a person clicks on the chat button, correlate that to the number of sales in GA.

I'm struggling how to set up the trigger to fire the event to send to GA.

Since the JS code loads custom HTML, is there a way to get it to track when the script is clicked on somehow so I know it's been used and send this info to GA?

Any ideas?

I basically want to know: "Did Customer service aid the user to make a purchase".

Thanks!

Nitesh

Comment: Yes you can do this. Can you post the configuration of the trigger that you are struggling to set up?

Comment: Hey Matus, the thing is I don't know how to set the trigger up to fire the GA event tag. This JS loads up an iframe and I really don't know how to get the trigger to fire. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There are tons of tutorials how to do it online if you just google "how to set the trigger up to fire GA event tag"... I don't think anyone will do the work for you here...

Comment: Im not struggling with setting up a tag Matus. I'm struggling with triggering a tag for a custom script as I cannot figure out how to trigger the tag. I cannot use a CSS identifier because its just a JS snippet and I dont know how to essentially say: "let me know when someone uses the live chat script" as the script has no callbacks I can use. This is where I'm struggling - i wanted to know if there is some way I can say "if someone interacted with the JS script in any way or clicked where the script was run, fire an event over to GA"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tidio [API](https://docs.tidiochat.com/#listeners-events) to trigger a dataLayer event when the Tidio window was opened: "To be able to use the API, you just need to insert Tidio Chat code into your website. You don't need any external libraries."

So for example to fire GTM dataLayer event when the Tidio window shows you just need to include this code on your page:

```
tidioChatApi.on('popUpShow', function(){
    // Your dataLayer event code
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'yourCustomEvent'
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can use "messageFromOperator" or "messageFromVisitor" events to only track visitors that interacted with an operator.

Comment: Can you please point me to Tidio documentation where they mention the "popUpShow" event. I can't find it. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith my answer is now 2 years old, looking at Tidio API they no longer have "popUpShow" event. Apparently valid events are: setStatus, messageFromOperator, messageFromVisitor, preFormFilled, resize, open, close. All can be found here: https://docs.tidiochat.com/#listeners-events